# Creating a ranking column from a queried column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I want to build a ranking column into my query--I've found some similar cases on Stack but this one's a little different and I can't quite make it work. I have a single table, EnrollmentX, with two columns, a unique StudentID and a GroupId (for sake of argument, groups 1:3). I need to simultaneously count the number of students in each of these three groups and then rank the the groups by number of students. I've made it as far as the counting:

```
SELECT
   EnrollmentX.GroupId,
   COUNT(EnrollmentX.StudentId) AS StudentCnt
FROM EnrollmentX
GROUP BY
   EnrollmentX.GroupId
```

This puts out two columns, one for GroupId, 1:3, and one for StudentCnt, with the correct number of students in each group. What I can't work out is how to use that StudentCnt column after building it to create a third ranking column.

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: Sorry, should remember to point this out--I'm on 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are on mysql 8 there are more readable options.Change the order in the inner query if you want a different rank.

```
SELECT GroupId, StudentCnt, @Rank:=@Rank + 1 AS rank FROM
(SELECT EnrollmentX.GroupId,
       COUNT(EnrollmentX.StudentId) AS StudentCnt
    FROM EnrollmentX
    GROUP BY
       EnrollmentX.GroupId
ORDER BY StudentCnt DESC
) x CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) y
```

Comment: Brilliant, that works and makes a lot of sense--part of my problem turns out to be some issue with "AS" on line 3, which kept breaking SELECT for me, so I think I may have been closer than I realized. For some reason my version (I am on 8) refuses to save variables with different names using AS.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how this solution would change in MS SQL? I'm new to SQL and trying to understand both versions as much as possible, and declaring variables seems to be very different in MS SQL.

Comment: @ThoureaulyRekt Forget about variables look into `RANK() over (partition by EnrollmentX.GroupId order by something desc)` for MS sql.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
select ex.GroupId, ex.StudentId, exg.cnt from EnrollmentX ex
left join (
    SELECT GroupId, COUNT(*) cnt 
    FROM EnrollmentX
    GROUP BY GroupId
) exg on ex.GroupId = exg.GroupId
order by exg.cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

try it..

```
SET @Rank = 0;
SELECT @Rank:=@Rank + 1 rank, EnrollmentX.GroupId,
       COUNT(EnrollmentX.StudentId) StudentCnt
    FROM EnrollmentX
    GROUP BY
       EnrollmentX.GroupId
ORDER BY StudentCnt DESC;
```